# What does the Bible say about gender segregation and free mixing of sexes in public places?

Tags: biblical-basis, sin, morality, gender, modesty

Islamic scholars [claim](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/11446/how-should-an-islamic-wedding-party-be) it is against Islamic rules to attend events where there is free mixing of men and women (such as concerts, proms and parties):

> There follows a list of haraam things which both men and women should
> avoid in the wedding party:
>
> **1- Mixing of men with women, and things that are involved in that, such as greeting and shaking hands with one another, and men and women
> dancing together, because all of that is haraam and is a very serious
> matter.**
>
> 2- Taking pictures, whether men do that amongst themselves or women do that amongst themselves.
>
> 3- Drinking alcohol or eating pork.
>
> **4- Letting the husband come in to where the women are in order to take his wife.**

Does the Bible preach similarly strict rules regarding the interaction of genders? Did early Christians also maintain strict division between men and women in public places to combat temptation and immorality?

Answer (score 2):

## Nope. The gender rules tend more to be about authority than the prevention of sexual immorality.

When the Bible is talking about sexual immorality, it generally says something along the line of "don't do it", rather than prescribing rules to try to prevent it. The onus is on the individual.

Instead, the gender restrictions in the Bible tend more to be about authority and gender roles. Women aren't to teach or lead men, husbands should love their wives while wives should obey their husbands, the passage where Paul denounces a group of pagan feminists who had become lesbians as an expression of their feminism, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So solely from a Biblical perspective, is it permissible for men and women to dance with one another at parties and other such events?

Comment: @a_sid I can't find anything like that, no. The closest thing I could find is Romans 14:13 which commands Christians not to knowingly put temptations in front of other Christians they know would be vulnerable to them, but that still largely puts the onus on the individual. If you know someone might be tempted to sexual immorality by a dance, don't invite them to the dance.

Comment: One would think that any environment which has music, alcohol and free mixing of men and women would be sexually charged.

Comment: @a_sid Drunken carousing is something that Christians aren't supposed to engage in, in general (there's multiple verses about that), but gender-mixed dancing in itself is fine - and if it's not fine for you, because you think you'll be tempted, then it's not fine for you, and other Christians should accept if you don't want to partake.

Comment: _.... and if it's not fine for you, because you think you'll be tempted, then it's not fine for you,...._ I cannot imagine how there will be no temptation when men and women are dancing with one another. I am perhaps unable to wrap my head around it because I was raised in a conservative environment.

Comment: The Bible never says wives are to obey their husbands. It does say they are to subject themselves to their husbands, which is similar but has subtle differences.

Comment: @curiousdannii Thank you for your input. _It does say they are to subject themselves to their husbands,..._ What does "subject" mean in this context? Did you mean 'subjugate"?

Comment: There is segregation between men and women in Jewish synagogues, but as pointed out in this answer, the husband is the head of his wife but his authority over her is to be considerate and loving. +1 although it would be helpful if you made reference to the specific Bible verses.

Answer (score 1):

> **1 Timothy 2** Complete Jewish Bible
>
> 2 First of all, then, I counsel that petitions, prayers, intercessions and thanksgivings be made for all human beings, 2 including kings and all in positions of prominence; so that we may lead quiet and peaceful lives, being godly and upright in everything. 3 This is what God, our Deliverer, regards as good; this is what meets his approval.
>
> 4 He wants all humanity to be delivered and come to full knowledge of the truth. 5 For God is one;[a] and there is but one Mediator between God and humanity, Yeshua the Messiah, himself human, 6 who gave himself as a ransom on behalf of all, thus providing testimony to God’s purpose at just the right time. 7 This is why I myself was appointed a proclaimer, even an emissary — I am telling the truth, not lying! — a trustworthy and truthful teacher of the Goyim.
>
> 8 Therefore, it is my wish that when the men pray, no matter where, they should lift up hands that are holy — they should not become angry or get into arguments.
>
> 9 Likewise, the women, when they pray, should be dressed modestly and sensibly in respectable attire, not with elaborate hairstyles and gold jewelry, or pearls, or expensive clothes. 10 Rather, they should adorn themselves with what is appropriate for women who claim to be worshipping God, namely, good deeds.
>
> 11 Let a woman learn in peace, fully submitted; 12 but I do not permit a woman to teach a man or exercise authority over him; rather, she is to remain at peace. 13 For Adam was formed first, then Havah. 14 Also it was not Adam who was deceived, but the woman who, on being deceived, became involved in the transgression. 15 Nevertheless, the woman will be delivered through childbearing, provided that she continues trusting, loving and living a holy life with modesty.
>
> **Footnotes** 1 Timothy 2:5 Deuteronomy 6:4

> **Deuteronomy 6:4** Complete Jewish Bible
>
> (A:vi, S: v) 4 “Sh’ma, Yisra’el! Adonai Eloheinu, Adonai echad [Hear, Isra’el! Adonai our God, Adonai is one];

> **Romans 13:13-14** Complete Jewish Bible
>
> 13 Let us live properly, as people do in the daytime — not partying and getting drunk, not engaging in sexual immorality and other excesses, not quarrelling and being jealous. 14 Instead, clothe yourselves with the Lord Yeshua the Messiah; and don’t waste your time thinking about how to provide for the sinful desires of your old nature.

> **Acts 15:19-20** Complete Jewish Bible
>
> 19 “Therefore, my opinion is that we should not put obstacles in the way of the Goyim who are turning to God. 20 Instead, we should write them a letter telling them to abstain from things polluted by idols, from fornication, from what is strangled and from blood.

There is a good site called Open Bible. It allows you to search for a term, and then it brings up many Bible scriptures.

Here is an example: https://www.openbible.info/topics/gender.

Another good site that works in conjunction with Open Bible is Bible Gateway. This site allows you to view the same piece of scripture using many different Bible translations.

As an example from the above Open Bible link:

> **Hebrews 13:4** ESV / 30 helpful votes Helpful Not Helpful
>
> Let marriage be held in honor among all, and let the marriage bed be undefiled, for God will judge the sexually immoral and adulterous.

The Bible Gateway Complete Jewish Bible version:

> **Hebrews 13:4** Complete Jewish Bible
>
> 4 Marriage is honorable in every respect; and, in particular, sex within marriage is pure. But God will indeed punish fornicators and adulterers.

And the Bible Gateway International Children's Bible translation is as follows:

> **Hebrews 13:4** International Children’s Bible
>
> 4 Marriage should be honored by everyone. Husband and wife should keep their marriage pure. God will judge guilty those who are sexually immoral and commit adultery.

Now, when you put all of this into the context of your question, as believers we are not meant to live as the non-believer. When we mix with the unbeliever we are in danger of becoming like them.

> **2 Corinthians 6:14-16** International Children’s Bible
>
> **Warning About Non-Christians**
>
> 14 You are not the same as those who do not believe. So do not join yourselves to them. Good and bad do not belong together. Light and darkness cannot share together. 15 How can Christ and Belial, the devil, have any agreement? What can a believer have together with a non-believer? 16 The temple of God cannot have any agreement with idols. And we are the temple of the living God. As God said: “I will live with them and walk with them. And I will be their God. And they will be my people.”

Now in public places such as music festivals and pubs, there is a real danger that intoxication can lead to regrettable behaviour for both males and females alike. And so, husband and wife should not attend separately, but together to prevent one being led astray by the Dajjal, since they can both enjoy themselves but also look out for one another!

Comment: Thank you for the response. _And so, husband and wife should not attend separately, but together to prevent one being led astray by the Dajjal, since they can both enjoy themselves but also look out for one another!_ Is this your opinion?

Comment: After seeing many Christians committing adultery, lusting, and getting drunk, yes.

Comment: I see. I am curious to know what the Bible says about settings where men and women can mix and casually interact with one another such as wedding parties in western countries. Does the Bible not prohibit that? nick012000's answer suggests this isn't the case.

Comment: Men and women are free to socialise and intermingle. But there is a danger of being led astray if not with each other. Especially, when you consider that in many settings alcohol is involved. Alcohol is shown to lead a person astray and cause a person to lose their salvation. Hence, drunkards, fornicators, and adulterers do not enter into the Kingdom of Heaven. A spirit filled person will be strong in Christ Jesus. But a weak person is very much open to temptation. And that is why it is better for husband and wife to attend together. Think Wedding in Cana and water turned into wine.

Comment: Is it wrong for a Christian husband and wife to attend separate churches? Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/separate-churches.html. "Genesis 2:24 tells us God created man and woman to become “one flesh” when they marry, not two separate beings who go their own separate ways. There is a unity in marriage that is unique and holy. Moreover, marriage is the picture of Christ and His church (believers) as described in Ephesians 5:31-32. The marriage covenant between a man and a woman is symbolic of the covenant between Christ and those for whom He died."